# Flume HDFS sink: Remove timestamp from filename

Tags: hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I have configured flume agent for my application, where source is Spooldir and sink is HDFS

I am able to collect files in hdfs.

agent configuration is:

```
agent.sources = src-1
agent.channels = c1
agent.sinks = k1

agent.sources.src-1.type = spooldir
agent.sources.src-1.channels = c1
agent.sources.src-1.spoolDir = /home/Documents/id/
agent.sources.src-1.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agent.sources.src-1.fileHeader=true
agent.channels.c1.type = file
agent.sources.src-1.basenameHeader=true
agent.sources.src-1.basenameHeaderKey=basename

agent.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.k1.channel = c1
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.path =hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/events/
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileHeader = true
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
```

I am having hdfs files as below format:

> /flume/events/file1.txt.1411543838171
>   /flume/events/file2.txt.1411544272696

I want to know Could i remove timestamp(1411543838171) / unique number which is generated automatically for each event for file name?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be possible to remove the timestamp just by using configuration. If you have a look at how HDFS Sink works you will find the following:

```
long counter = fileExtensionCounter.incrementAndGet();
String fullFileName = fileName + "." + counter;
```

Where `fileExtensionCounter` is `fileExtensionCounter = new AtomicLong(clock.currentTimeMillis());`

You can check the code for the sink [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.flume.flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/1.6.0/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java#HDFSEventSink.0filePath) and [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.flume.flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/1.6.0/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java#BucketWriter.0fileExtensionCounter) for the writer.

If what you want to do is put more events in a single file, then you can have a look at the sink properties

- `rollTime`
- `rollSize`
- `rollCount`
- `batchSize`